# Cassandra, custom types - Is it possible to extend custom type later?

Tags: cassandra

I have created a custom type in cassandra:

```
CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS my_type (
    id ascii,
    name ascii
);
```

I use this type in my new table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT exists person
(
    id my_type,
    name ascii
);
```

Is it possible to extend custom type later (add new fields, etc.) - after create database schema? For example when my structure changes and I will need to add some fields into this type, would Cassandra complains about it or it is easy and I could just change custom type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a limited support for schema evolution of the user-defined data types:

- You can add new fields to UDT
- You can rename the existing field

But you can't do:

- Drop existing field from UDT
- Change the type of the existing field

See [documentation on ALTER TYPE command](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/cql_commands/cqlAlterType.html).